# Round last digit integer to nearest 9

Tags: python

**Set-up**

I have a set of prices with decimals I want to end on the nearest `9`, where the cut-off point is `4`.

E.g. `734` should be `729`, `734.1` should be `739` and `733.9` should be `729`.

Prices can be single, double, triple, and quadruple digits with decimals.

---

**Try**

```
if int(str(int(757.2))[-1]) > 4:
    p = int(str(int(757.2))[:-1] + '9')
```

Now, this returns input price `757.2` as `759`, as desired. However, if the input price would be ending on a `3` and/or wouldn't be a triple-digit I wouldn't know how to account for it.

Also, this approach seems rather cumbersome.

Is there someone who knows how to fix this neatly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the typical round to `10` and shift by `1` before and after:

```
def round9(n):
    return round((n+1) / 10) * 10 - 1

round9(737.2)
# 739
round9(733.2)
# 729
round9(734.0)
# 739
round9(733.9)
# 729
```

Comment: Per the example, 734 should be rounded *down* to 729

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, try:

```
import math
def nearest(n):
    if n%10 > 4:
        return math.ceil(n/10)*10 - 1
    return math.floor(n/10)*10 - 1

>>> nearest(734)
729

>>> nearest(734.1)
739

>>> nearest(733.9)
729
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the integer division by 10 with a condition on the remainder, and multiply by ten to get the nearest 10, then subtract 1:

```
def nearest9(n):
    d,r = divmod(n,10)
    return int(d+(r>4))*10-1

>>> nearest9(734.1)
739

>>> nearest9(734)
729
```

Comment: `734.1` should round to `739` per the question

Comment: That is the wrong cutoff. `734.1` -> `739`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones thanks I had misread the question, it is fixed ;)

Comment: @user2390182 thanks for the feedback, read too quickly, I fixed it, I think your answer is incorrect on the threshold though

Comment: Agreed, the way it is specified. I like to think of it as wrongly demanded :D team "ROUND_HALF_UP" all da way!